# bootstrap nav bar toggling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my code for a nav-bar. Can someone please help me in activating the toggle button. It does not respond on click. I just want it to toggle the content of sidebar-wrapper. I want it to be completely visible and once I click on the button it should disappear and should come back once I hit the toggle button again. Am pretty new to this. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2" style="border:none;"><span class="fa-stack"> <i class="fa fa-bars fa-stack-2x "></i></span></button></li>
                </ul>
                <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 20px; padding-top: 7px;">
                    <a href="http://sunlightfoundation.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
                    <p style="display: inline"><b>Congress API</b></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: black">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-stacked" id="menu">
                    <li class="active" onclick="showMainDivision('legislate','bills','committees','favourites')">
                        <a ng-click="getLegislators()"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Legislators</a>
                    </li>
                    <li onclick="showMainDivision('bills','legislate','committees','favourites')">
                        <a ng-click="getActiveBill()"> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Bills</a>
                    </li>
                    <li onclick="showMainDivision('committees','bills','legislate','favourites')">
                        <a ng-click="getCommittees()"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Committees</a>
                    </li>
                    <li onclick="showMainDivision('favourites','committees','bills','legislate');">
                        <a ng-click="getFavourites()" id="fav_load"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Favourites</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleDIV(DIV)
{
    if(document.getElementById(DIV).style.display=="none")
    {
        document.getElementById(DIV).style.display="block"
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById(DIV).style.display="none"
    }
}

// use it like:
// onClick="toggleDIV('myDivName')";
```

Comment: I need it to slide to the left and the content div to occupy that space